# HTTP Request doesn’t include query

Tags: node.js, http, http-post

I am trying to send a POST request with query parameters using the request library. I have succeded in sending these requests, but I am still unable to include any working query.

I have followed instructions from other posts and concluded that I’ve tried everything on the internet that is related to my mission.

This is the code that does comply with what I found on the internet:

```
const request = require(’request’);

request.post({
    url: 'https://example.com/endpoint',
    qs: { with_counts: true } },
    function (err, res, body) {
        console.log(err, body);
    }
);
```

This, however, does not work. The server does not recieve the query. I tried setting the `body` and `json` properties instead, but those didn’t work either.

I cant tell what I’m doing wrong, and I realize that it might not be possible for you to tell, but this is my last desperate attempt before giving up and switching to Python.

Comment: Are you using node backend or something else?

Comment: @Sanket To be frank, I am not the backend. A company called Discord is. The reason I know that the query is not recieved is because it does not respond with the data that it is supposed to, had it recieved the parameters. Visiting the URL in a browser with `?with_counts=true` works just fine.

Comment: Ok, you can generate the nodejs request code with the Postman. Check it out using Postman.